# Multiple XML file paring into a single CSV

Tags: python, r, xml, xml-parsing

I have multiple XML files present in a folder and need to retrieve information of few tags In Excel want to retrieve details of `AbstractText Label="FINDINGS"`, `AbstractText Label="IMPRESSION"`, and `parentImage id` tags and store this information from all the XML files into a csv.

From the given sample XML file I want to retrieve details of `AbstractText Label="FINDINGS"`, `AbstractText Label="IMPRESSION"`, and `parentImage id` and store this information from all the XML files in an Excel sheet.

Edit: I want to know how can I get these details for all the `.xml` files present in a single folder and write this information as columns and their respective values from these xml tags into a single csv.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<eCitation>
    <meta type="rr"/>
    <uId id="CXR49"/>
    <pmcId id="49"/>
    <docSource>CXR</docSource>
    <IUXRId id="49"/>
    <licenseType>open-access</licenseType>
    <licenseURL>http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/</licenseURL>
    <ccLicense>byncnd</ccLicense>
    <articleURL/>
    <articleDate>2013-08-01</articleDate>
    <articleType>XR</articleType>
    <publisher>Indiana University</publisher>
    <title>Indiana University Chest X-ray Collection</title>
    <note>The data are drawn from multiple hospital systems.</note>
    <specialty>pulmonary diseases</specialty>
    <subset>CXR</subset>
    <MedlineCitation Owner="Indiana University" Status="supplied by publisher">
        <Article PubModel="Electronic">
            <Journal>
                <JournalIssue>
                    <PubDate>
                        <Year>2013</Year>
                        <Month>08</Month>
                        <Day>01</Day>
                    </PubDate>
                </JournalIssue>
            </Journal>
            <ArticleTitle>Indiana University Chest X-ray Collection
</ArticleTitle>
            <Abstract>
                <AbstractText Label="COMPARISON">None.
</AbstractText>
                <AbstractText Label="INDICATION">XXXX-year-old with
osteoarthritis of the hip scheduled for total hip replacement.
Preoperative evaluation.
</AbstractText>
                <AbstractText Label="FINDINGS">The heart, pulmonary XXXX and
mediastinum are within normal limits. There is no pleural
effusion or pneumothorax. There is no focal air space opacity to
suggest a pneumonia. There are degenerative changes of the
thoracic spine. There is a calcified granuloma identified in the
right suprahilar region. The aorta is mildly tortuous and
ectatic. There is asymmetric right apical smooth pleural
thickening. There are severe degenerative changes of the XXXX.
</AbstractText>
                <AbstractText Label="IMPRESSION">No acute cardiopulmonary
disease.
</AbstractText>
            </Abstract>
            <Affiliation>Indiana University</Affiliation>
            <AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
                <Author ValidYN="Y">
                    <LastName>Kohli</LastName>
                    <ForeName>Marc</ForeName>
                    <Initials>MD</Initials>
                </Author>
                <Author ValidYN="Y">
                    <LastName>Rosenman</LastName>
                    <ForeName>Marc</ForeName>
                    <Initials>M</Initials>
                </Author>
            </AuthorList>
            <Language>eng</Language>
            <PublicationTypeList>
                <PublicationType>Radiology Report</PublicationType>
            </PublicationTypeList>
            <ArticleDate>
                <Year>2013</Year>
                <Month>08</Month>
                <Day>01</Day>
            </ArticleDate>
        </Article>
        <EssieArticleTitle>Indiana University Chest X-ray                 Collection</EssieArticleTitle>
        <IMedAuthor>Marc David Kohli MD</IMedAuthor>
        <IMedAuthor>Marc Rosenman M</IMedAuthor>
    </MedlineCitation>
    <MeSH>
        <major>Thoracic Vertebrae/degenerative</major>
        <major>Calcified Granuloma/lung/hilum/right</major>
        <major>Aorta/tortuous/mild</major>
        <major>Thickening/pleura/apex/right</major>
        <automatic>calcified granuloma</automatic>
        <automatic>degenerative change</automatic>
        <automatic>pleural thickening</automatic>
    </MeSH>
    <parentImage id="CXR49_IM-2110-1001">
        <figureId>F1</figureId>
        <caption>PA and lateral chest radiographs dated XXXX at XXXX hours.
</caption>
        <panel type="single">
            <url>/hadoop/storage/radiology/extract/CXR49_IM-2110-1001.jpg</url>
            <imgModality>7</imgModality>
            <region type="panel">
                <globalImageFeatures>
                    <CEDD>f2p0k1205</CEDD>
                    <ColorLayout>f1p0k137</ColorLayout>
                    <EdgeHistogram>f0p0k184</EdgeHistogram>
                    <FCTH>f4p0k2450</FCTH>
                    <SemanticContext60>f3p0k74</SemanticContext60>
                </globalImageFeatures>
            </region>
        </panel>
    </parentImage>
    <parentImage id="CXR49_IM-2110-2001">
        <figureId>F2</figureId>
        <caption>PA and lateral chest radiographs dated XXXX at XXXX hours.            </caption>
        <panel type="single">
            <url>/hadoop/storage/radiology/extract/CXR49_IM-2110-2001.jpg</url>
            <imgModality>7</imgModality>
            <region type="panel">
                <globalImageFeatures>
                    <CEDD>f2p0k710</CEDD>
                    <ColorLayout>f1p0k83</ColorLayout>
                    <EdgeHistogram>f0p0k1200</EdgeHistogram>
                    <FCTH>f4p0k369</FCTH>
                    <SemanticContext60>f3p0k18</SemanticContext60>
                </globalImageFeatures>
            </region>
        </panel>
    </parentImage>
</eCitation>
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible code and expected outputs clearly.

Comment: Hi Santosh, Thanks for your reply. I want each xml tag specified above (Parent Image, AbstractText label="Finding", AbstractText label="Impression") as column headers in a csv and their respective row values should be the data enclosed in these attributes. There are 4000 xml files and each of them has similar format. All of these files have a unique image id and their respective findings associated with them. I need complete enclosed data. How can I do that. I am completely new to XML.

Comment: Let's start with one file at a time shall we? Is it okay if a function can parse one file and return the list of dictionaries or some format, per file?

Comment: Yes Santosh, I am completely fine as long as I receive the required data. I need a single csv with all 4000 xml files info in 1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your xml exists in xmldoc.txt, the following script will fetch you the required values in form of a list . You may modify the code to suit your needs.

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'W'])#change it to what you want
for f in xmlfiles: # xmlfiles is a list of strings where each one is the absolute path to your xml files
    tree = etree.parse(f)
    findings = tree.find(".//AbstractText[@Label='FINDINGS']")
    impression = tree.find(".//AbstractText[@Label='IMPRESSION']")
    parentimages = tree.findall(".//parentImage")
    x = [findings,impression]
    y = [i.text for i in x]
    z = [i.attrib['id'] for i in parentimages]
    y.extend(z)
    df.loc[len(df)] = y
df.to_csv('everything.csv',header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Just 1 question, I have got .xml file, will it run for that as well?

Comment: Extension of the file doesn't matter as long as it's a text file. And of course, xml is a type of text file. Happy coding. :)

Comment: Yes this worked really well...THANK YOU so much. But I want to know how can I get these details for all the .xml files present in a single folder? And secondly how can I write this information as columns and their respective values in a csv?

Comment: You need to update those questions in the question above, possibly as subqueries, tagged by an "EDIT:" for any of us to answer.

Comment: Hey...I tried implementing the above edit but I am getting following error:
OSError: Error reading file 'C': failed to load external entity "C"

Comment: I added the file path after import command as "xmlfiles = 'C:/Users/Apurva/Desktop/2019/OPENI/NLMCXR_reports/ecgen-radiology'